# Is there a catalog of all UI widgets and their names, platforms and languages?

Tags: windows, user-interface, widget

I was looking at the Firefox Add-ons Manager UI (pictured below) and really liked the expandable list used to show settings or properties for each add-on.

[Firefox Add-ons Manager http://uploads.tech-buzz.net/Firefox3Beta3ComingonMonday_859/get_addons.png](http://uploads.tech-buzz.net/Firefox3Beta3ComingonMonday_859/get_addons.png)

I liked it enough to want to include something similar in one of my applications.  The problem is, I don't know, exactly what the control is called (it doesn't seem to be "expandable list"), nor do I know if there is an implementation available for use in my own application (so I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.)

This isn't the first time that I've seen some cool piece of UI and wanted to incorporate it into something I'm working on, but have had no idea if I would have to design it from scratch.  So I generally end up reworking my UI to use standard UI widgets to save time.

This got me thinking, is there some place that has a catalog of a bunch of UI widgets with names and what platforms/languages they are implemented for/in?

**UPDATE**

Turns out this control is called a Rich List Box, and it seems to only be implemented in XUL.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no, there isn't a universal catalog anywhere, though MSDN is as good a place as any to find definitions of most common UI elements.

The specific widget you ask about is generally called an [accordian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)) (wikipedia)